Does anyone know what Psatlees is more than it has something to do with silk?
All I know is that Psatlees is some kind of silk or silk garment. It is mentioned in a letter from 1867. The letter is written in German or Swiss-German and is written in a letter from the merchant Huth & Co. in London to Näf & Soehne in Zürich.

Btw, the letter (from the other question) is written in standard German, not in Swiss German or any other regional variant. And there is no hint that the writer was Swiss – only the addressee.

This page gives some important hints. A report has a table of prices for raw silk. The different qualities are grouped under three headings – Organsins, Trames and Grèges. These three are the French names commonly used for different stages in the production of silk yarn.
German Wikipedia explains:

Drei bis acht Kokons bzw. Filamente werden zusammen abgewickelt oder gehaspelt (sogenannte Haspelseide), kleben aufgrund des Seidenleims zusammen und bilden ein sogenanntes Grège, einen Seidenfaden...
Mehrere gehaspelte Seidenfäden werden miteinander verzwirnt. Durch unterschiedliche Zwirntechniken entstehen funktionsangepasste Schuss- und Kettfäden. Dabei wird...als Organzin (oder Organsin) ein Zwirn bezeichnet, der aus zwei oder drei Grègen hergestellt wird, die ihrerseits bereits verdreht sind; diese Garnqualität kann für Webketten eingesetzt werden. Trame-Garn dagegen wird aus zwei oder mehr ungedrehten Grègen verzwirnt und eignet sich nur als Schußmaterial.

Translated with DeepL.com:

Three to eight cocoons or filaments are unwound or reeled together (so-called reeled silk), stick together due to the silk glue and form a so-called grège, a silk thread...
Several reeled silk threads are twisted together. Different twisting techniques are used to create functionally adapted weft and warp threads. The term Organzin (or Organsin) refers to a twisted yarn made from two or three Grèges, which are themselves already twisted; this yarn quality can be used for weaving warps. Trame yarn, on the other hand, is twisted from two or more untwisted Grèges and is only suitable as weft material.

In the above mentioned table, Psatlée is listed under Grèges, as a lower quality (third choice) thread. Like all other technical terms used for silk production, it seems to be a french word, so for further investigation you'll need to ask elsewhere.
